# Как оптимизировать SQL-запрос (или MySQL-таблицу) для ускорения его выполнения?

Tags: mysql, sql, yii, оптимизация, select

Имеется такая MySQL-таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mails` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `to` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `object` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  `temp_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mailing_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `priority` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `send_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `error` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Таблица наполнена данными, сейчас порядка: 350 тыс. записей.

В цикле к данной таблице выполняется несколько тысяч запросов (3000-10000 штук) одного и того же вида:

```
SELECT `id`, `to` FROM `mails` WHERE (`to` LIKE 'info@mail.ru' OR `to` LIKE 'info@mail.ru,%' OR `to` LIKE '%,info@mail.ru' OR `to` LIKE '%,info@mail.ru,%') AND `mailing_id` = 172
```

Вопрос: **как оптимизировать данный SQL-запрос (или саму MySQL-таблицу) для увеличения скорости его выполнения?**

p.s.: запрос выполняется в **Yii 1.x** через конструктор запросов: Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select("id, to")->from('{{mails}}')....

Comment: А сколько у вас в таблице в среднем записей с конкретным mailing_id ? И есть ли индекс на это поле

Comment: И краеугольный камень быстрого выполнения множества одинаковых запросов - что бы в PDO/mysqli prepare выполнялся один раз и потом уже этот подготовленный запрос выполнялся много раз с привязанными переменными. Как это в фреймворке происходит не знаю. Возможно нужен один create и множественное выполнение. главное что бы этот create много раз не приходилось делать

Comment: С конкретным mailing_id - у меня может быть от 3 до 10 тыс. записей.

Comment: Про один подготовленный запрос и множественное выполнение не знал, где такое почитать?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: 3-10к конечно много. нужна большая селективность. а выборка по email  по индексу вообще не пойдет в таком варианте как сейчас. там что ли список email через запятую ? Тогда вам правильно советуют выносить в отдельную таблицу. причем если один email повторяется много (сотни-тысячи) раз может оказаться эффективным завести табличку в которой email будут выдаваться id и связующую между этой mails и id-адресов. (правда если там у вас регистрируется всякий спам который обычно с непредсказуемых email повторяющихся по 1-2 раза на всю БД - то такой подход только замедлит)

Answer (score 1):

**По-быстрому:**
переключитесь на использование *innoDB* вместо *myisam* (в нём *Like* быстрее работает) и добавьте индекс по полю `to`.

**Если этого окажется мало:**
Вынесите содержимое столбца `to` в отдельную таблицу так, чтобы в одной строке был один *e-mail*. Связь организуйте "один ко многим" используя [`foreign key`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Должно выйти что-то вроде:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mails` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `to_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `object` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  `temp_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mailing_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `priority` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `send_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `error` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `recipients` (
  `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `rec_id` int unsigned not null,
  `to` varchar(255) NOT NULL not null,
  INDEX pn_rec_index(`rec_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`rec_id`) references mails(`to_id`) on delete cascade,
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Индекс по полю to бесполезен при таком like да еще с OR, он в принципе использоваться не будет. Составной индекс (mailing_id, to) выглядит куда лучше. он хоть и будет делать like перебором, но перебором нескольких страниц индекса для данного mailing_id, а не для всей таблицы. (это касается в основном решения "по быстрому")